# A "generic" error occurred in GDI+ is killing me

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, file-upload, iis-7

I am trying to resize and save the user-uploaded image in a folder using fileupload control. But on bmp.save(..), i get this exception.

**Exception Type**: System.Runtime.InteropServices.ExternalException

**Error Message**: A generic error occurred in GDI+.

**Stack Trace**:    at System.Drawing.Image.Save(String filename, ImageCodecInfo encoder, EncoderParameters encoderParams)
   at btnUpload_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e)

**Here is my code**

```
   If fileUpload1.HasFile Then
        Dim flStream = fileUpload1.FileContent
        Dim imgMemStream = New MemoryStream

        imgMemStream.SetLength(flStream.Length)
        flStream.Read(imgMemStream.GetBuffer, 0, flStream.Length)

        imgMemStream.Flush()
        flStream.Close()

        Dim imgStream = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(imgMemStream)
        Dim bmp = New Bitmap(200, 200)
        Dim gr = Graphics.FromImage(bmp)
        gr.DrawImage(imgStream, 0, 0, 200, 200)

        If System.IO.Directory.Exists(Server.MapPath("ProfilePics\")) Then
            bmp.Save(Server.MapPath("ProfilePics\" & employeeId & ".jpg"), Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg)
        Else
            Throw New Exception("Path not found")
        End If

        imgStream.Dispose()
        bmp.Dispose()
        gr.Dispose()

        Response.Redirect(Me.Request.Url.AbsolutePath) 
End If
```

I also tried giving iis_wpg full control to that folder.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like a permissions issue to me (which you've started to investigate it sounds like).  Have you tried giving NETWORK SERVICE permission to write to that folder?

If that doesn't work, try to just write a text file out to that folder to determine if it is permissions, you should get a better error with those methods.  I seem to recall that in IIS sometimes you need to also enable write permissions in both the file system and via IIS but that might be outdated info.